# How to extract jpeg image DC Coefficients with the PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have read through all the possible related Q&A to this question.  I'm using Python 2.7.14 and the Python Image Library (PIL).  I would like to extract the Quantized DCT values of an existing jpeg image.  I'm specifically looking to extract the DC coefficient associated with each 8x8 pixel area.  I'm not interesting in changing or re-encoding, I just want to obtain the DC values [0,0].  This lower level function does not seem to be accessible from either methods or attributes associated with the Image class.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt there's an existing API that will give you that information. However the PIL (nowadays the pillow fork) is open source, so you could look at its code to see if there's some method you could use. If not, you can even modify it if necessary. You can also send suggestions for new functionality to the folks working on pillow which was being actively maintained last time I checked.

Comment: I share those doubts too and i don't think Pillow will want this functionality. Your best bet is some very low-level wrapper (if existing) for libjpeg and co. or directly working with it.

Comment: I have been experimenting with matplotlib.image in order to obtain the quantized DC coefficients for a jpg, but I'm still not there.  Does anyone have an example or suggestion that uses matplotlib to accomplish this.  Thanks again, for the responses.